# getSalesforceBaseUrl() returning an error in Anonymous

Tags: rest-api, url, execute-anonymous, remote-site-settings

I want to execute a call to Lightning Platform REST API in Anonymous window.
When I am writing  the following:

```
String sfURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
```

I am getting the following error:

> method does not exist or incorrect signature void
>   getSalesforceBaseUrl() from the type String

I have checked and the sandbox URL is specified in the Remote Site Settings, since this is a preliminary condition. 
I do not know if this is regarding the fact that I use the Anonymous Window to execute the code directly. Is there any restriction for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error occurs when you have something else defined as "Url", something like

```
String url = 'whatever';
...
String sfURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
```

In that case, SF understands `URL` as your variable and not the one you are expecting.

I'd say you have 2 options,

1. Change your declaration of `whatever` to a different name
2. Use `System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();` instead

Comment: I have tried this as well before writing this question @Sergio Alocer but this was not the cause. I got the same error. Actually I have tried to put the code in a class and then execute it and it worked so the problem is that Anonymous window does not recognize that method for some reason. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried using the `System.` prefix? In my Execute Anonymous window it works

Comment: Oh, sorry. You're right. I was not noticing the difference. Indeed, adding that prefix works, but not adding it results in an error. Thank you very much.